# ERROR - Android Push Notification using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM)

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-cloud-messaging

I am working on android push notification and try to get the registration id so that I can send push notification from my asp.net admin page to my android device, but my application crashed whenever I try to run the application, please help me.

My XML file

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.gcmdemo.MainActivity" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/display"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My Java file

```
package com.example.gcmdemo;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicInteger;
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager.NameNotFoundException;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";
public static final String PROPERTY_REG_ID = "registration_id";
private static final String PROPERTY_APP_VERSION = "appVersion";
private final static String TAG = "GCMDEMO";
//My sender ID
protected String SENDER_ID = "10xxxxxxxxx53";
TextView mDisplay;
GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
AtomicInteger msgId = new AtomicInteger();
SharedPreferences prefs;
Context context;

String regid;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     mDisplay = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display);
     context = getApplicationContext();
     if (checkPlayServices()) {
            gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);
            regid = getRegistrationId(context);
            if (regid.isEmpty())
            {
                 registerInBackground();
            }
            else
            {
            Log.d(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
            }
      }
    }

private void registerInBackground() {
     new AsyncTask() {

          protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) 
          {
               String msg = "";
               try 
               {
                    if (gcm == null) 
                    {
                             gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(context);
                    }
                    regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);               Log.d(TAG, "########################################");
                    Log.d(TAG, "Current Device's Registration ID is: "+msg);     
               } 
               catch (IOException ex) 
               {
                   msg = "Error :" + ex.getMessage();
               }
               return null;
          }     protected void onPostExecute(Object result) 
          { //to do here };
       }}.execute(null, null, null);
         }


private String getRegistrationId(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     final SharedPreferences prefs = getGCMPreferences(context);
        String registrationId = prefs.getString(PROPERTY_REG_ID, "");
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }

        int registeredVersion = prefs.getInt(PROPERTY_APP_VERSION, Integer.MIN_VALUE);
        int currentVersion = getAppVersion(context);
        if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
            Log.i(TAG, "App version changed.");
            return "";
        }
        return registrationId;
    }
private int getAppVersion(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        PackageInfo packageInfo = context.getPackageManager()
                .getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
        return packageInfo.versionCode;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        // should never happen
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
    }
}
private SharedPreferences getGCMPreferences(Context context) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.class.getSimpleName(),
                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this,
                    PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "This device is not supported - Google Play Services.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
protected void onResume()
{
       super.onResume();       
       checkPlayServices();
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

My Android Manifest

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.gcmdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.gcmdemo.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".GcmIntentService" />

    <receiver
        android:name=".GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <actionandroid:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />

            <category android:name="com.example.gcmdemo" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

MY ERROR LOG

```
 10-22 20:55:05.360: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.360: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.370: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.370: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.480: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.500: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.520: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.530: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.530: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.530: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
10-22 20:55:05.680: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:05.690: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:05.690: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:05.690: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:05.690: E/SurfaceFlinger(54): glCheckFramebufferStatusOES error 760856444
10-22 20:55:05.700: E/SurfaceFlinger(54): got GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE_OES error while taking screenshot
10-22 20:55:05.700: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:05.700: E/libEGL(54): called unimplemented OpenGL ES API
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Process: com.example.gcmdemo, PID: 1311
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.gcmdemo/com.example.gcmdemo.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: A required meta-data tag in your app's AndroidManifest.xml does not exist.  You must have the following declaration within the <application> element:     <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.zzad(Unknown Source)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(Unknown Source)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.example.gcmdemo.MainActivity.checkPlayServices(MainActivity.java:118)
10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at com.example.gcmdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:44)
```

10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
    10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
    10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    10-22 20:55:07.080: E/AndroidRuntime(1311):     ... 11 more
    10-22 20:55:09.490: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:09.490: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
10-22 20:55:09.500: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.500: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.530: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/Effect_Tick.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.530: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressStandard.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.540: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressSpacebar.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.540: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressDelete.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.540: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressReturn.ogg
    10-22 20:55:09.540: E/SoundPool(389): error loading /system/media/audio/ui/KeypressInvalid.ogg
    10-22 20:55:19.560: E/Drm(57): Failed to open plugin directory /vendor/lib/mediadrm
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks.
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'end' not called
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at java.util.zip.Inflater.(Inflater.java:82)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:96)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at java.util.zip.GZIPInputStream.(GZIPInputStream.java:81)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.initContentStream(HttpEngine.java:468)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.readResponse(HttpEngine.java:666)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:347)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:296)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:503)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:136)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:811)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.a(SourceFile:776)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:676)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.http.GoogleHttpClient.execute(SourceFile:660)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.j.a(SourceFile:220)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:263)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.a.a(SourceFile:132)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.appcert.b.a(SourceFile:43)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.b.a(SourceFile:62)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:120)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.b.a.a(SourceFile:61)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.auth.be.cron.AuthCronService.a(SourceFile:44)
    10-22 20:55:20.140: E/StrictMode(693):  at com.google.android.gms.gcm.al.run(SourceFile:135)

Comment: What is the format of the request being used to send the message from your .Net application?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply, my .net is in c#

Comment: Are you creating the request to send the GCM message to the device? In any case you are not using the recommended way of using GCM on Android, have a look at this quickstart and use that as a base for your application. https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

Comment: Thanks! But I have switched from using GCM to PARSE for my push notification, I am able to send notification from parse server to my android phone, I am still trying to figure out a way to send notification from asp.net c# to my android phone using parse

Answer (score 0):

From your `logcat`, it shows that you need to do as follows:

In your `Android Manifest`add the following tag as a child of the  element:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

You can add the lines between `</receiver>` and `</application>` in your `AndroidManifest` file.

Comment: This is Android emulator issue. To workaround it just disable all sounds in Android settings (particularly "Touch sounds").